# time derivative of a function with one variable depending on time

Tags: derivatives

With $f(x)$ a function of $x$ and $x(t)$ a function of time does $\frac{df(x)}{dt}=0 $ ?

thanks.

Comment: Chain rule! You must measure the impact on $x(t)$ when  nudging $t$, and the impact on $f(x(t))$ when nudging $x(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not $0$.

By the chain rule;

$\frac{d(f(x(t)))}{dt} =  f'(x(t))\cdot x'(t)$

Comment: Good to see *The Integrator* using the chain rule ! Just kidding and $+1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici in these trying times who am I to question the calculus god and their mystic ways?

Comment: This could make an interesting post (hoping it would not be closed too fast) !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Let us hope the MSE Gods have mercy and spare this post.